# Sending an Email without Outlook

Tags: vba, email

Access can use easily Outlook, but my computer doesn't have Outlook. Can I use instead of another form? Our company only use gmail so I need to connect to gmail after click on a button on a form.

My button code:

```
Private Sub Gmail_Click()

    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim objMail As Object

    On Error Resume Next 'Keep going if there is an error
    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") 'See if Outlook is open

    If Err Then 'Outlook is not open
       Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'Create a new instance
    End If
    'Create e-mail item
    Set objMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With objMail
    'Set body format to HTML
     .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
     .To = "something@domain.com"
     .Cc = "something@domain.com"
     .Subject = "Subject LIne"
     .HTMLBody = "<htmltags>Body Content</htmltags>"
     .send
    End With

    MsgBox "Operation completed successfully"

End Sub
```

Comment: By different form, I assume you mean a different method of emailing. Have you looked into `SMTP` (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol). Also, you might want to remove the email addresses from the post.

Comment: Have a look at this collection: [7 Command Line Utilities to Easily Send Email Using SMTP](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/sending-email-using-command-line-useful-for-downtime-alert-notification/)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer solution later. I just create a label with hyperlink addres, where we can set up text to diplay, e-mail address, subject. So if you click on this label it is lead to the standard mail system like gmail. I hope it was helpful for some other people.